# oneToMany association for single inheritance entity

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine, sti

I have following issue with the single table inheritance mapping for Doctrine ORM aka STI.

It seems as if it's impossible to have a oneToMany association from the STI entity to another entity.

I have 2 entities **Customer** and **Supplier**, with very similar fields. Which is why I want to use the single table inheritance option in Doctrine to get these 2 entities in one table with a simple 'type' column so to indicate what entity the row belongs to. **AbstractBusiness** class will serve as a **base class** for these 2 entities.

Consider this entity mapping for AbstractBusiness.

```
Axelvnk\CRMBundle\Entity\AbstractBusiness:
    type: entity
    table: axelvnk_crm_business

    inheritanceType: SINGLE_TABLE

    discriminatorColumn:
        name: type
        type: string

    discriminatorMap:
        customer: Axelvnk\CRMBundle\Entity\CustomerInterface
        supplier: Axelvnk\CRMBundle\Entity\SupplierInterface

    id:
        id:
            type: guid
            generator:
                strategy: UUID

    fields:
        vatNumber:
            type: string

        label:
            type: string

    oneToOne:
        billingAddress:
            targetEntity: Axelvnk\CRMBundle\Entity\AddressInterface
            joinColumn:
                name: billing_address_id
                referencedColumnName: id
            cascade: ["all"]

    oneToMany:
        addresses:
            targetEntity: Axelvnk\CRMBundle\Entity\AddressInterface
            mappedBy: business
            cascade: ["all"]
```

This would be the mapping for the Customer entity

```
Axelvnk\CRMBundle\Entity\Customer:
    type: entity
```

This would be the mapping for the Supplier entity

```
Axelvnk\CRMBundle\Entity\Supplier:
    type: entity
```

For the time being no additional fields. But it wouldn't make a difference for this issue.

Now the **AbstractBusiness::billingAddress** property refers to an instance of an **Address** entity. Which is mapped like this :

```
Axelvnk\CRMBundle\Entity\Address:
    type: entity
    table: axelvnk_crm_address

    id:
        id:
            type: guid
            generator:
                strategy: UUID

    fields:
        streetAndNumber:
            type: string

        city:
            type: string

    manyToOne:
        business:
            targetEntity: Axelvnk\CRMBundle\Entity\AbstractBusiness
            inversedBy: addresses
            joinColumn:
                name: business_id
                referencedColumnName: id
```

As you can see the **Address::business** property refers back to the STI entity, being the AbstractBusiness. This can be either a **Supplier** or a **Customer** depending on the owning side..

I would expect doctrine to resolve which entity class to hydrate to since it knows AbstractBusiness is a STI entity and the discriminator map is in place. After querying the business table with the business_id in the address table, it should be able to figure out the class based on the "type" column in the address table, right? But apparently it doesn't. I can't map back to the STI entity because doctrine can't make proxy classes from Abstract classes, which makes sense I guess.

But my question now is, what is the right way to map back to the STI entity? Or is this just impossible in Doctrine?

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: I have association mappings to STI entities in my projects and they work just fine, but base entity is not defined as `abstract` in my case.

Comment: But then the base entity should be included in the discriminator map... And it will then probably try to hydrate to that class instead, and thats not what i want.

Comment: No, it should not. Here is discriminator map definition from real project for different types of content. Base entity is named `Content` and is not `abstract`: `@ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"photo"="Photo", "video"="Video", "comics"="Comics"}) `

Comment: That's weird, what version? This is the exception I get when i do this "Entity 'Axelvnk\CRMBundle\Entity\Business' has to be part of the discriminator map of 'Axelvnk\CRMBundle\Entity\Business' to be properly mapped in the inheritance hierarchy. Alternatively you can make 'Axelvnk\CRMBundle\Entity\Business' an abstract class to avoid this exception from occurring."

Comment: In your case I mean that `AbstractBusiness` should not be part of discriminator map (and it is not from what I see) and should not be abstract class. `Business` and `Supplier` should be instantiable classes inherited from `AbstractBusiness`. Btw, you're using `CustomerInterface` instead of `Customer` into your discriminator map, maybe it is wrong, try to use explicit entity class names instead

Comment: Not sure what your pointing at. Why shouldn't it be abstract? And you mean that Customer and Supplier should be instantiable classes that extend AbstractBusiness, yes they are already.. And I'm using interfaces yes, but it gets resolved by a listener from doctrine into the actual concrete classes, no worries.

Comment: Is these interface resolution is correctly stored into `ClassMetadata`? Doctrine uses information from this source for its operations.

Answer (score 1):

So apparently, using interfaces in the discriminatorMap and then using the doctrine target entity resolver to replace these interfaces with concrete classes works perfectly to persist entities, but to fetch them, it can't figure out what class to hydrate...

So the solution : always use concrete classes in the discriminatorMap...

There's an open issue on github to support resolving the classes/interfaces in the discriminator map the same way it works for targetEntity properties : https://github.com/doctrine/orm/issues/7622